# how to switch a class calling another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

This is original function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.itemove', function() {
    $('.itemoveact').removeClass('itemoveact');
    $(this).addClass('itemoveact');
});
```

Now I want to do the same by calling another function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.itemove', function() {
    swclass('itemoveact');
});

function swclass(c){
    $('.' + c).removeClass(c);
    $(this).addClass(c);
}
```

Nothing happens. There is a problem with passing `this` context.

Any help?

Comment: Bind? Arrow function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.apply()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.itemove', function() {
   swclass.apply(this, ['itemoveact']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `swclass` function

```
function swclass(c){
   $('.' + c).removeClass(c);
   $(this).addClass(c);
}
```

`this` is just a *reference* which points to `window` object.

One solution is to use `bind` method.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.itemove', function() {
    swclass.bind(this)('itemove');
});

function swclass(c){
    $('.' + c).removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('blue');
}
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
.blue{
   color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="itemove red">Hello</p>
```

Comment: class to be switched is dinamically changed it's not always 'red` or `blue` or anything.

Comment: @puerto,I just created an example in order to show you how to use bind method.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$(document).on('click', '.itemove', function() {
    swclass.bind(this)('itemoveact');
});

function swclass(c){
    $('.' + c).removeClass(c);
    $(this).addClass(c);
}
```

> swclass.bind(this)('itemoveact');

bind function will apply the scope of your '.itemove' to swclass function and then make a call.

This read would help
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can jump through some hoops to change the value of `this`, but it’s easier and simpler to pass it as an argument:

```
$(document).on('click', '.itemove', function() {
    swclass('itemoveact', this);
});

function swclass(c, addTo){
    $('.' + c).removeClass(c);
    $(addTo).addClass(c);
}
```